# Why Is This Babylon.js Material Not Working? - Red And Black Checkerboard Error

Tags: babylonjs

I am trying to learn how to create a cube using a jpg or png I want. I have added an alpha channel to a jpg and then exported this to a png file. I then added the path to this file in a Babylon.js program. However when I execute the program in the Babylon.js playground I only see the cube covered in red and black boxes like a checker board. In the example they are just passing in some png file with an alpha channel from wikipedia.

The example I am following is located at this URL: https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/materials#transparent-texture-examples

The example that anyone can tweak and modify in their web browser is located here: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#YDO1F#18

**The example works, however how does one add their own image they are interested  in seeing on the cube?**

I was going to ask this in the babylon.js forum but apparently there is not such a device.

Please find the code that I am trying to modify as follows:

```
var createScene = function() {
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 3 * Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 5, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
    camera.attachControl(canvas, false);

    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
  light.intensity = 0.7;

  var pl = new BABYLON.PointLight("pl", BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), scene);
  pl.diffuse = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
  pl.specular = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
  pl.intensity = 0.8;

  var mat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("dog", scene);
  mat.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Alaskan_Malamute%2BBlank.png", scene);
  mat.diffuseTexture.hasAlpha = true;
  mat.backFaceCulling = false;
  var box = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", {}, scene);
  box.material = mat;

    return scene;
};
```

I thought the only line to modify would be the argument to BABYLON.Texture(). When I modify this to a png with an alpha channel or a regular jpeg or anything else I see the cube as only a red and black checkerboard. If you have the time and patience please try this for yourself. What are the odds that a babylon.js wiz is lurking this forum?

Comment: https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#YDO1F#18 - this link renders as expected: with a dog picture texture

Comment: Try to add your own image though. That is my question. Why can I not add my own image by editing the parameter in the `new BABYLON.Texture()` method?

Comment: Any link you have at hand?

Comment: This link will give the red and black checkerboard error: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Night_sky#/media/File:171213-N-PW494-0013_(38274679075).jpg

Comment: @zerkms Do you really get 4 day work weeks in New Zealand? I have read about awesome working conditions such as this for NZ. :) Anyway thank-you for the help sirs.

Comment: This PNG image with a transparent background will also not work. :/ https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Universe#/media/File:Andromeda_Galaxy_(transparent_background).png

Comment: It works if you provide a correct direct link to an image https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#YDO1F#85 Btw, I'm not sure if the second link with "transparent" background is actually transparent: to me it looks like an RGB filled with white opaque background. PS: I'd say not generally :-) I have a "normal" 8am-5pm 5 days work week

Comment: I was able to change the texture with some of the textures here: https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/playground_textures I then saved the sample as a zip file. On my disk I added the png I initially wanted and it works. What do you mean "direct link" I though the path to the file was a direct link? You know protocol://domain/folder/file.png Also, thanks for the info on NZ working conditions. I will have to visit there some day. :)

Comment: Wow I see you were able to add that specific image of space I initially sent you. :) Cool man. Thank-you for the help.

Comment: I provided a direct link for another image I found and I receive the red and black checkerboard. I was able to add this image locally and get it to work though. Strange.

Comment: Probably that link is not direct enough or the remote server explicitly forbids hotlinking